# Как получить из fetch данные а не промис

Tags: javascript, fetch, асинхронность

Как с помощью fetch дождаться именно данных а не Promise
Условно есть псевдокод

```
function(){
  let a
  fetch(url).then(resp => resp.json()).then(resp => {a = resp.name})
  return a
}
```

при таком подходе вернется undefined т.к. return выполняется быстрее присваивания. Как сделать что бы функция или вообще любая асинхронная операция возвращала именно результат а не промис?

Comment: Никак, асинхронные функции именно потому и асинхронные, что данные не могут появиться сразу и нужно дождаться их появления с помощью промиса

Comment: Обрати внимание на этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1476674/191482

Comment: А по моему больше заслуживает внимания [этот ответ](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/554291#554291).